# Flutter using Timer for background work, any disadvantages / problems?

Tags: flutter, service, timer, background

In my flutter app, I need some background work to be done. The functionality is to check stored transactions in the local sqlite db and post them to the backend (this is done to offer off-line availability to app users).
This background process only needs to run when the user is logged in, so if the app is terminated by the user or the OS, my background functionality should stop as well, but if the app goes out of focus (to the background) my background service should continue to run.

I checked the flutter WorkManager package https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager and Dart Background Processes https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes and both are more than what I need, as they both offer running in the background when the app is terminated, which is not my requirements.

Also I need access to user information (like access tokens, whether user is logged in and some parameters) that will be difficult to retrieve if I use either models (as they run in a separate process). I would have to save the required data to the DB and check on launch of my background service if the user is logged in from the DB and get necessary parameters as well.

I am thinking of using a periodic Timer (Timer.periodic) as the callback continues to execute every n duration, even when the app is not in foreground, but stops once the app is killed. Is there any reason why a Timer would not be a good way to implement what I need? I am not familiar with drawbacks of using Timer and was wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Use Timer in an Isolate. Won't affect your main process

Comment: But I am trying to avoid using an isolate because I can't access the app data in an isolate and I need to (need to know if user is logged in and need to load a certificate from the assets, need to logout the user on some conditions ..etc) 
Is there a problem if I use it directly in the app without an isolate? Does it affect the app?